# ec2 SSH tunnel not working?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up a  node following [Creating a Personal Privoxy/Tor/Proxy EC2 Instance](http://sickbits.net/creating-a-personal-privoxytorproxy-ec2-instance/) using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on **Amazon EC2**. I've gotten to:

```
$ ssh ubuntu@ec2-blah.amazonaws.com -i .ssh/Amazon-Proxy.pem.txt -L50000:localhost:8118 -f -N
```

when I run :

```
  d@d-PC ~
  $ ssh ubuntu@52.***.**.** -i f:/tproxy.pem -L50000:localhost:8118 -f -N      

  d@d-PC ~
  $ netstat -an -f inet -L      

  Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections.      

  NETSTAT [-a] [-b] [-e] [-f] [-n] [-o] [-p proto] [-r] [-s] [-t] [interval]      

    -a            Displays all connections and listening ports.
    -b            Displays the executable involved in creating each connection or
                  listening port. In some cases well-known executables host
                  multiple independent components, and in these cases the
                  sequence of components involved in creating the connection
                  or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable
                  name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called,
                  and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option
                  can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient
                  permissions.
    -e            Displays Ethernet statistics. This may be combined with the -s
                  option.
    -f            Displays Fully Qualified Domain Names (FQDN) for foreign
                  addresses.
    -n            Displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.
    -o            Displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.
    -p proto      Shows connections for the protocol specified by proto; proto
                  may be any of: TCP, UDP, TCPv6, or UDPv6.  If used with the -s
                  option to display per-protocol statistics, proto may be any of:
                  IP, IPv6, ICMP, ICMPv6, TCP, TCPv6, UDP, or UDPv6.
    -r            Displays the routing table.
    -s            Displays per-protocol statistics.  By default, statistics are
                  shown for IP, IPv6, ICMP, ICMPv6, TCP, TCPv6, UDP, and UDPv6;
                  the -p option may be used to specify a subset of the default.
    -t            Displays the current connection offload state.
    interval      Redisplays selected statistics, pausing interval seconds
                  between each display.  Press CTRL+C to stop redisplaying
                  statistics.  If omitted, netstat will print the current
                  configuration information once.
```

Obviously this is not the expected output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks to me that Windows' `netstat` doesn't have `-L` - probably calls it something else. You should ask on [su].

Comment: ok I did that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, One of the issues is I should have been using :

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2---*-.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com -i f:tproxy.pem -L50000:localhost:8118 -f -N
```